# "explicit template argument list not allowed" with g++, but compiles with clang++?

Tags: c++, templates

I have test code as below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<typename Cont>
class Test
{
    template<typename T, typename = void> static constexpr bool check = false;
    template<typename T>
    static constexpr bool check<T, std::void_t<typename T::iterator>> = true;

public:
    static bool fun()
    {
        return check<Cont>;
    }
};

int main([[maybe_unused]] int argc, [[maybe_unused]] char *argv[])
{
    cout << Test<vector<int>>::fun() << endl;
    cout << Test<int>::fun() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Compile with g++, compiler will complain:

```
test.cpp:12:27: error: explicit template argument list not allowed
   12 |     static constexpr bool check<T, std::void_t<typename T::iterator>> = true;
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

But the clang++ compiles the code without any error.

What does the error g++ thorws mean?
How can I modify the code that both g++ and clang++ compiles it?

Thanks!

Comment: This [seems to be reported](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=100231) (and acknowledged) as a gcc bug.  The bug seems to specifically involve a partial template specialization of a template variable in class scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be ok to write a partial specialization [in any context](http://cpp.report/temp.spec.partial.general#6)

It is listed as a gcc bug but it is *not* fixed yet: [gcc bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=71954)

As a workaround you can place the specialization outside class context like:

```
template<typename Cont>
class Test 
{
    template<typename T, typename = void> static constexpr bool check = false;

public:
    static bool fun()
    {    
        return check<Cont>;
    }    
};
template<typename Cont>
template<typename T>
constexpr bool Test<Cont>::check<T, std::void_t<typename T::iterator>> = true;

int main([[maybe_unused]] int argc, [[maybe_unused]] char *argv[])
{
    cout << Test<vector<int>>::fun() << endl;
    cout << Test<int>::fun() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "_Template specialization is not allowed in class context._": Is that true? The standard even has an example of a partial specialization in a class definition (although for a nested class): https://www.eel.is/c++draft/temp#spec.partial.general-example-3 Also note the preceding paragraph stating that the partial specialization may appear anywhere that a definition of the primary template may appear.